# Send cucumber 'index.html' report to email

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have created a testing automation framework using cucumber+appium.
But after executing the framework i want to send the report (/target/cucumber/index.html) over email as mail body, but unable to do the same.
The same thing i did with 'testng emailable-reports.html' and it works like charm.
I tried with:-
1. Jenkins using 'extended email plugin' for selenium .html report it works fine but for cucumber it is not working.
2. using java mail api (jsoup library).

Also as i right click on cucumber index.html report then it shows below code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cucumber Features</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="formatter.js"></script>
    <script src="report.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cucumber-report"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i tried with java mail api, firstly i extract html and then tried to send the html but it send blank report.
Please help how i can send the full html report as email body, also this reports contains attached 'screenshots', attached is the structure of /target/cucumber/ folder:-
[image]

Please help!!

email send code:-

```
public class Email {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SendGridException {

        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/config.properties");
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.load(fin);         



        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(); 

        try     
        { BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+prop.getProperty("reports"))); 
        String str; while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { path.append(str); } in.close(); } catch (IOException e) { } String content = path.toString();

        System.out.println("HTML IS :---" +path);



        SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();

        try {
            String[] toList ={"suresh.s@gmail.in","suresh98714@gmail.com"};
            email.addTo(toList);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            String emailTo = "suresh98714@gmail.com";

            email.addTo(emailTo);
        }

        email.setFrom("suresh98714@gmail.com");


        try {
            SMTPAPI smtpapi = email.getSMTPAPI();

            String[] cc ={"suresh.s@cashify.in","suresh98714@gmail.com"};
            email.setCc(cc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {// for bcc
            String[] bcc = {"",""};
            email.setBcc(bcc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        email.setSubject("Cucumber Report");
        email.setHtml(path.toString());

        SendGrid.Response response =sendGrid.send(email);
        System.out.println("Response is " +response.toString());    




    }
```

Expected email over email body (attached screenshot):-
[image]

Comment: can you give code sample and/or exceptions

Comment: email end code?

Comment: yes, how exactly do you send the html report to email and etc. code sample

Comment: @Infern0:- added my email sent code, pls help!!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the cucumber folder under target has the JS and CSS files apart from the `index.html` file that you want to send as an attachment in an email. The Html file is consuming those files as dependencies so you can't send the HTML file individual and that's why you are getting a blank file.

One solution is to zip the whole cucumber folder and send as attachment and other is to write a customized wrapper to create your own standalone  HTML report using `cucucmber.json` file.